# Android SlidingTabs Blending Background Colors

Tags: android, colors, tabs, android-viewpager, blending

I have a ViewPager and a SlidingTabLayout (uses com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0) that works fine. The transition used is the DepthPageTransformer. My question is how could I have a different color for every tab/fragment and when I change tabs it smoothly blends to the tab color. I would also like the same thing to happen to the tabs, toolbar, and the very top bar. Help would be very appreciated!

An example would be the 360 Security App (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qihoo.security&hl=en)

```
    public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
        // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setTranslationX(0);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);
    } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
        // Fade the page out.
        view.setAlpha(1 - position);

        // Counteract the default slide transition
        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
}
```